# How to focus on editable textfield when checkbox is checked in ExtJS Grid?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I am creating a grid with  checkcolumn and celledit. I have 3 columns 1 is for checkboxes and other is editable text field and 3rd is the productname, using celledit to edit the price.

When I will check a checkbox on a record the focus should be on the textfield for that particular record.

Here is the code sample:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.EntryPage',
{
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.entryPage',
title : 'Product Price Entry',
store : 'ProductStore',
loadMask: true,

plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1})],

initComponent:function(){

    var me = this;
    this.selModel = {xtype:'cellmodel'},

    this.columns = {
                defaults:{sortable : true,hideable : true,menuDisabled : true,align : 'left',style : 'text-align:left'},
                items:[
                          {

                              xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                              header: 'Check Me',
                              dataIndex : 'active',
                              listeners:{

                              checkchange : function( CheckColumn, rowIndex, checked, eOpts ){
                              // Select the textfield

                              }}
                          },
                          {
                               text : 'Price',
                               flex:0.75,
                               sortable : false,
                               hideable : false,
                               dataIndex : 'unitprice',
                               editor: 'textfield'
                          },
                          {
                               text : 'Product Name',
                               flex:2,
                               dataIndex : 'pname'
                          }
                    ]};

        //this.features = [];
        this.callParent(arguments);

} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of listener(use edit event), if it has been checked, get the reference of record and apply focus() method.

Refer below link for reference.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit

see the edit event in the above link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows:

```
  checkchange : function( CheckColumn, rowIndex, checked, eOpts ){

         //me.getPlugin('cellplugin').startEdit(record,1);     
         me.getPlugin('cellplugin').startEditByPosition({row: rowIndex, column: 1});        

   }}
```

This worked.... Hariharan thanks for your answer!!