# Ext js check column - change focus on checkchange

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

**What I want to have happen:**
After clicking a checkbox in a row, set focus on another column in the same row.

**What is actually happening:**
Focus is set on the other column, but focus is lost almost immediately.
Focus returns to the row, rather than the checkbox (or staying with the text area).

I've tried a few different options for changing focus using plugins RowEditing and CellEditing, but the focus does not persist.

I thought adding a delay might do the job, but I can't configure the listener correctly to use a delay.
I also thought adding a preventDefault call in the checkchange listener might do the job as well, but I haven't figured out what the event is inside checkchange to call preventDefault on.

The listener (added as part of the CheckColumn config) is defined as:

```
listeners: {
  checkchange: function(cc, index, ischecked, eOpts){
    console.log(arguments);
    if (ischecked){
      //  focus on price input box
      item_grid.plugins[0].startEdit(index, 6);
      // prevent default here would be helpful, as it would hopefully
      // keep the focus from jumping back to this column from the text column
      // I am having trouble capturing what the event is in this listener
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked at [How to focus on editable textfield when checkbox is checked in ExtJS Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079921/how-to-focus-on-editable-textfield-when-checkbox-is-checked-in-extjs-grid) but that only changes the means of changing focus; focus still jumps back to the row.

Comment: The checkchange listener doesn't take in an event as an argument, so I can't just do e.preventDefault().

The first arg to the listener is 'this', which is the checkcolumn object, not the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution/workaround that I decided on was to just delay the change in focus event until after the checkchange listener was finished it's execution.

I'm not 100% with this, but it works for now.

```
listeners: {
  checkchange: function(cc, index, ischecked, eOpts){
    if (ischecked){
      Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function(){
        //  focus on price input box
        item_grid.plugins[0].startEdit(index, 6);
      }).delay(150);
    }
  }
}
```